# Angular agGrid with complex cell renderer and nested angular components has poor performance, how to improve it

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I had implemented a cell renderer just like docs says:

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/

However my cell renderer is complex and is pretty heavy: it contains some nested angular components that get updated and re-rendered when data from multiple data fields change (I display allowed actions).

With big set of data I've noticed that performance degrades, and when I removed custom cell renderer columns it improved. Cell renderer has `refresh` function that should return `true` if I handle refresh manually, or `false` if renderer should be recreated. Initially I had it set to false.

The issue I have is that when I switched to `return true` to improve performance, then the cell is not updated. But when I have `return false`, it gets updated, but my cell renderer components get recreated too often which is causing performance issues.

To me it seems that when cell renderer has a nested angular components, something bad is happening with perhaps change detection, or agGrid is not properly refreshing the cell, because I don't see changes. I tried injecting change detector, call manually detectChanges / markForCheck and all in vain.

http://54.222.217.254/javascript-grid-performance/#3-create-fast-cell-renderers recommends not to use framework renderers, but I have to do it.

Is there a way to optimise it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation that you linked to explains, cell renderers get created and destroyed frequently, and the pattern isn't particularly predictable.

The way to make cell renders performant is, well, to make your cell renderers performant in the face of being created and destroyed frequently.

And, as the documentation explains, the way to do that is to not use framework components, but rather simple functions. And if you must use framework components, they need to be as lightweight as possible.

But you state that "my cell renderer is complex and is pretty heavy".
It may be difficult, but what you need to do is to make your renderer less complex, and more lightweight. There's not much outside of that that you can do.